# how to find how many times does something appears in a list recursively (python)

Tags: recursion

imagine if i had a list ([1,2,2,3,2]) and i want to find how many times does the number 2 appear in the list, how would i do it recursively, do i set my counter to 0 in my base case? How do i make the list count my desired item.

```
def rc_count(L, x):
    if len(L)==0:
        n=0
        return n
    else:
        rc_count(L[1:], x)
        if L[0]==x:
            n+=1
        return n
```

it says local variable n referenced before assignment so where should i put my counter

Comment: The problem is this line - ```n+=1``` you should try to understand the *implications*. BTW, if some post did help you, you should acknowledge it and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really se the reason for this recursive function. However this is how you would do it:

```
def rc_count(l,x):
    n = 0
    if not l:
        return n
    else:
        n = re(l[1:], x)
        if l[0] == x:
            n+=1
    return n
```

Here `rc_count([1,2,2,2,2,3,4,5],2)` will return `4`

Comment: Nice.  But You should elaborate and try to answer why the change helps solve the OP's problem